# Python SSLError: ('Certificate validation failed') authenticating on Figo API

Tags: python, api, ssl, restful-authentication

I'm trying to log in to [figo's API](http://docs.figo.io/)

But when I try to exchange the authentication_code for an authentication_token and finally be able to use the API, I get the following error:

```
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\figo\figo.py", line 69, in connect
    raise ssl.SSLError("Certificate validation failed")
ssl.SSLError: ('Certificate validation failed',)
```

I am running this from my local machine nd this is my code so far:

```
import webbrowser
from figo import FigoConnection, FigoSession


client_id = 'CaESKmC8MAhNpDe5rvmWnSkRE_7pkkVIIgMwclgzGcQY'
client_secret = 'STdzfv0GXtEj_bwYn7AgCVszN1kKq5BdgEIKOM_fzybQ'
redirect_url = 'http://localhost:3000'
state = 'qweqwe'

connection = FigoConnection(client_id, client_secret, "http://localhost:3000")

def start_login():
    # open the webbrowser to kick of the login process
    webbrowser.open(connection.login_url(scope="accounts=ro transactions=ro", state=state))

def process_redirect(authentication_code, state):
    # handle the redirect url invocation, which gets passed an authentication code and the state (from the initial login_url call)

    # authenticate the call
    if state != "qweqwe":
        raise Exception("Bogus redirect, wrong state")

    # trade in authentication code for access token
    token_dict = connection.convert_authentication_code(authentication_code)

    # start session
    session = FigoSession(token_dict["access_token"])

    # access data
    for account in session.accounts:
        print account.name
```

The steps I follow after setting up the functions are:

```
start_login()
```

This redirects me to my webbrowser, demands my login credentials and another confirmation for linking the test accounts I have in that profile to the API.
When I log in, I get redirected again to my redirect URL
and the following url appears in my browser:

```
http://localhost:3000/?state=qweqwe&code=OVzBFGDQD6pyHjs9BAJZCzdYku9exPZoN5uBVbxfpHVjJ9JYQmQmEKxyVKSJK0PSV2xYCNvT7AyZHa3b36Whn3DXMV-mJfHoMJWMHgk7Yi4M
```

In this url is the code I need to exchange for the auth_token, so I copy it from the webbrowser manually and do the following:

```
authentication_token = 'OVzBFGDQD6pyHjs9BAJZCzdYku9exPZoN5uBVbxfpHVjJ9JYQmQmEKxyVKSJK0PSV2xYCNvT7AyZHa3b36Whn3DXMV-mJfHoMJWMHgk7Yi4M'

process_redirect(authentication_code, state)
```

And that is when I receive the error.
I guess this issue comes in [connection() function of the API.](https://github.com/figo-connect/python-figo/blob/master/figo/figo.py)

but I can't figure out how this function determines my ssl is not the correct one.